# Don't understand why my Taylor expansion results in a message and an unexpected result

Tags: replacement, series-expansion

Trying to do something simple: Taylor expand a generic function of `t` around a point `t` and substitute `t0 + h` for `t`. Here's my expression:

```
y1[t0_, h_] = Module[{t}, Series[y[t], {t, t0, 2}] /. t -> t0 + h]
```

This results the message

> SeriesData::sdatv: First argument h + t0 is not a valid variable.

and it gives the result

> ```
> y[t0] + y′[t0]((h + t0) - t0) + 1/2 y′′[t0] ((h + t0) - t0)^2 + O[(h + t0) - t0]^3
> ```

This is what I'm looking for, except all of the `(h + t0) - t0` stuff. Why is this not simplifying to `h`? In fact, if I substitute 6 for t0, I get `(h + 6) - 6`. So there is enough information there to know that when it substitutes for `t0`, it substitutes for all `t0`, but it still treats one of the `t0`'s as different from the other for purposes of simplification.

I sense that I'm missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

Change the argument of `y` to `t0 + h`

```
y1[t0_, h_] = Module[{t}, Series[y[h + t0], {h, 0, 2}]]

(* SeriesData[h, 0, {y[t0], Derivative[1][y][t0], Derivative[2][y][t0]/2}, 0, 3, 1] *)
```

Comment: Why not just `y1[t0_, h_] = Series[y[h + t0], {h, 0, 2}]`

Comment: @m_goldberg left the expression enclosed in the `Module`, in case the OP had some reason to have it there.  You are correct that it does nothing in this toy problem.

Comment: The Module construct was there because the variable t is local and gets replaced by the substitution. Not needed any more. Thanks!